# Create flat ndarray from DataFrame column containing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with a column including numpy arrays:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Arrays': [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 
                           np.array([4, 5, 6]),
                           np.array([7, 8, 9])]})`
```

I need to extract the data in a way that I get a 2-dimensional array out of it. Like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]])`
```

But `df.values` results in an array containing a list of arrays:

```
array([[array([1, 2, 3])],
    [array([4, 5, 6])],
    [array([7, 8, 9])]], dtype=object)`
```

Is there an operator for this kind of problem or do I need to loop over all entries?

Comment: Are you sure it's a duplicate @coldspeed? The question you pointed to is about flattening into 1-dimensional array whereas the OP clearly mentions 2 dimensions.

Comment: @ayorgo Yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `concatenate` and `flatten` to get a single flattened array out of array of arrays

```
np.concatenate(df.values.flatten())
```

Alternative is to use `ravel`

```
np.concatenate(df.values.ravel())
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Arrays': [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 
                               np.array([4, 5, 6]),
                               np.array([7, 8, 9])]})

np.concatenate(df.values.flatten())

# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Finally, to get a 2d array, you can simply use `reshape` as

```
np.reshape(flattened_array, (len(df),len(df)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine for me.

Comment: @MetalPesto: You are welcome. Glad to help :)

Comment: @MetalPesto: If you untimately want a 2d array, you can now simple reshape it using `np.reshape`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from

```
df.applymap(list).values.ravel()
```

you can also do

```
df.applymap(list).values.reshape((-1,))
```

giving you

```
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

or, otherwise

```
df.applymap(list)['Arrays'].tolist()
```

resulting in

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```